# Using LINQ's .Any() on a DataTable

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have a datatable loaded up with some records and I am then pulling a query from another file and want to check if the ID that I pull in this query exists in my datatable.

```
foreach (var item in records)
{
    bool hasit = dt.AsEnumerable().Any(p => p.Field<string>(0) == item.ID);
    if (!hasit)
    {
        //Logic
    }
}
```

I'm using that .Any() function and expecting it to return true if there is an ID in the first field of the datatable that matches the id in the records collection. It continually returns false though, am I missing something? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Try setting a blank enumerable to the result of `dt.AsEnumerable().Any(p => p.Field<string>(0) == item.ID);` and seeing what you get back.

Comment: maybe change `!hasit` to `hasit`?

Comment: This looks pretty inefficent for a large number of items in the `records` collection. Can you rewrite this to use a "where field 0 is contained in a list of "ID" columns from the records collection" type query?

Comment: it's obviously that the your comparison has something wrong, you should try some debug with step-by-step executing it to see what happens.

Comment: Perhaps your datatable field is not **exactly** the same as your item.ID. For example, if your item.ID "Test" it will not match "TEST" or "TEST ".

Answer (score 2):

> I'm using that `.Any()` function and expecting it to return true if there is an ID in the first field of the datatable that matches the id in the records collection. It continually returns `false`

When one uses `==` it compares object references. I recommend you instead use `Equals` which will *just* compare the values. Hence change your statement to

```
dt.AsEnumerable().Any(p => p.Field<string>(0).Equals(item.ID))
```

Which will achieve what you are expecting.

Answer (score 1):

The method
    .Any(p => p.Field(0) == item.ID)

will return true IF ANY element is found. Your posted code specifies that the next thing you do is ask

```
if (!hasit)
{
    //Logic
}
```

which means if(NOT any has it)... which is producing the incorrect behavior. Change it to:

```
if (hasit)
{
    //Logic
}
```

and you'll get the desired results.

Edit: kudos to [Cuong Le for the observation.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18470481/using-linqs-any-on-a-datatable#comment27147462_18470481)

Comment: That assumes he wants to do something if there are any elements, it may be he wants to run the logic if there are no elements.

Comment: Yea I see what you mean but you're right bendataclear, I want to do logic if it is not true.

Answer (score 0):

I would try breaking it up to see if I could find the error:

```
foreach (var item in records)
{
    var enumer = dt.AsEnumerable(); // <-- Check this to make sure it has elements
    var filtered = enumer.Any(p => p.Field<string>(0) == item.ID); // <- Check to make sure it has elements

}
```